# Select all td's at a certain level in a table when it contains nested tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that roughly looks like this:

```
====================
|  td  |  td*       |
|      | |==========|
|      | |td*| td&  |
|      | |td*|======|
|      | |td*|td&|td|
|      | |   |======|
|      | |==========|
====================
```

I want to select the  elements by their position in the hierarchy; for example I want to select all 's marked with * or all td's marked with &

The `tr td:nth-child()` selector doesn't work for me as there are nested tables and so the selector is applied to them as well.

I am fine with jQuery or javascript approach.

Here is the HTML layout:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Label1
        </td>
        <td name="level-2">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td name="level-2">Label2
                    </td>
                    <td name="level-3">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td name="level-3">Label3</td>
                                <td name="level4">Value3</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

when I do `$('table tr td:nth-child(2)');` it selects the whole parent `level-2` td including the contents, but NOT the second level-2 td.

The names are illustrative only.

Comment: Possible to show what you've got so far? That might help us visualize your issue.

Comment: Your ASCII image is not clear. Please post the HTML structure.

Comment: Added the HTML layout and the jQuery I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you to implement some recursive javascript function to get each `td` level of the table, Then get all `td` elements of that table and pass the selector of that `td` to the function to take its level. So in each iterate you have its td level.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick as long as you don't use the same name for other td's.

[name=level-num] selects by the name "level-num" (change it by the name of the td's you want, you can also search by value or id, etc.).

".each" simply selects every elements indicated (in this case, every td's with the name "level-num").

```
$(td[name=level-num]).each(function(){
    $(this).something; //do something with every td that has the name "level-*Level Number*"
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work at all because the rendered html does NOT have name tags. Hence me saying 'The names are illustrative only.' in the question.

Comment: Then, how do you identify them? Is it with a class?

Comment: Hence the question :) I can find the first table in the document and I need to traverse the DOM from there.